# Find from a set of distributions which ones are within the area most of another distribution

Tags: r

```
z4log <- c(0.0279 , 0.0002, 0.0191, -0.0329,- 0.0002,- 0.0322, 0.0204, 0.0229, -0.0057, 0.0181, 0.0192, 0.0018, -0.0209, 0.0398, -0.0039, 0.0355, 0.0528, 0.0064, 0.0227, -0.0035, 0.0206, 0.0305, -0.0185, -0.0218, -0.0118, -0.0292, 0.0309, 0.0277, 0.0270, 0.0052, 0.0066, -0.0080,- 0.0066, 0.0002, 0.0006,- 0.0339, 0.0432,- 0.0115,- 0.0225,- 0.02,0.0118, 0.0151, 0.0011, 0.0162, 0.0020, 0.0306, -0.0222, -0.0255, 0.0464, 0.0155, 0.0020, -0.0235, 0.0094, 0.0154, -0.0251, 0.0229, 0.0464, 0.0158, -0.0085, 0.0146, -0.0283, 0.0492, 0.0084, 0.0262, -0.0223, 0.0389, 0.0092, -0.0032, -0.0178, -0.0308, -0.0208, -0.0131, -0.0155, 0.0031, 0.0273, -0.0154, 0.0501, -0.0253, 0.0392, 0.0821, -0.0092, -0.0097, 0.0195, 0.0522, -0.0466, -0.0309, -0.0038, 0.0365, 0.0448, 0.0193, 0.0403,- 0.0639, -0.0413, 0.0613, 0.0504, 0.0183, -0.0138, -0.0096, 0.0683, 0.0238, 0.0245, 0.0012, 0.0393, -0.0274, 0.0388, 0.0568, -0.0321, -0.0134, -0.0062, 0.0458, -0.0143, 0.0143, 0.0310, 0.0203, -0.0516 , 0.0572, 0.0470, -0.0403, 0.0649, 0.0285, -0.0215, 0.0766, -0.0650, -0.0302, 0.0705, -0.0459, 0.0265, 0.01193, -0.0050, -0.0827, -0.0016, -0.0312, 0.0088, 0.0264, 0.0478, 0.0337, 0.0638, -0.0058, 0.0530 , 0.01195,- 0.01114, 0.0207, 0.01018,- 0.0585,- 0.0115, 0.0069, 0.0071, 0.0546,- 0.0268, 0.01000,- 0.01081,- 0.0614, 0.01144,- 0.0466,- 0.0380, 0.0732, 0.0479, 0.0548, 0.0742,- 0.0776,- 0.0109, 0.01346, 0.0458, 0.0057, 0.0748,- 0.0523,- 0.0332,- 0.0295, 0.0072, 0.0002, 0.0448, 0.01245,- 0.0756,- 0.0402,- 0.0366, 0.0175,- 0.0313, 0.0153,- 0.0050,- 0.0128,- 0.0433, 0.0282, 0.0754, 0.0250, 0.0710, 0.01604,- 0.0151, 0.0355,- 0.0424, 0.01009,- 0.0858, 0.0531,- 0.0193,- 0.0364,- 0.0016,- 0.0613, 0.01312, 0.0920, 0.0150, 0.0327, 0.0802,- 0.0148, 0.0853, 0.0323, 0.0135, 0.01106, 0.0452,- 0.0565, 0.0118, 0.0919,-0.01297, 0.0996,0.0834)

# Generating Multiple Distributions 

library(wmtsa)
wavelet<- wavelet<- c("s14","d14","c14")
# Selection of n.levels = what range of frequencies I am interested at j0 (RANGE FROM TO)
nlevel<- seq(1: as.integer (floor (logb ((length(z4log)),base=2))))
schrinkfun <- c("soft","hard","mid")    
threshfun <- c("universal", "adaptive", "minimax")
threshscale<- c(0.55,0.65,0.75,0.85,0.95)

# Generating Benchmark Distribution 

x <-  as.vector((z4log))
w2<- expand.grid(wavelet=wavelet,nlevel=nlevel,schrinkfun=  schrinkfun,threshfun= threshfun,threshscale= threshscale, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
result <-  mapply(function(m,k,p,u,l,x)  (wavShrink(x, wavelet= m, n.level =k, shrink.fun = p, thresh.fun =u, threshold=NULL, thresh.scale = l, xform="modwt", noise.variance=-1, reflect=TRUE)), w2$wavelet,  w2$nlevel , w2$schrinkfun,  w2$threshfun, w2$threshscale ,MoreArgs=list(x= (x)))

# Plot Comparison Distributions

Dist  <-  density(z4log)
plot(Dist, type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", col="red", lwd=3, ylim=c(0,2* max(density(z4log)$y)), xlim=c(min(density(z4log)$x),-min(density (z4log)$x))) # pdf

j <- seq(1:(length(result)/length(z4log)))
fun <- function (x) lines(density(result[,x]))
lapply(j,fun)

lines(Dist, type="l", xlab="x", ylab="y", col="red", lwd=3, ylim=c(0,2* max(density(z4log)$y)), xlim=c(min(density(z4log)$x),-min(density (z4log)$x))) # pdf
```

As you can see from the plot where 40,000 distributions are ploted against the red distribution. some are within the distribution and some others exceed the red distribution limits.

My objective is to find out which distributions from the 40,000 lay within the main distribution. For this I use the overlap function but this function as you will see tells me the fit not if the lack of fit is within the distribution which is my objective.

```
# simulate two samples
AA <- z4log
b <- function(x) result[,x]
f <- seq(1:dim(result)[[2]])
BB <- lapply(f,b)

# same dataframe before rescaling. You'll need to load the ‘scales‘ library. But first add a "Source" column to be able to distinguish between a and b after they are combined.
a = data.frame(value = AA, Source = "a" )
fun <- function(x) data.frame(value = BB[[x]], Source = "b")
b = lapply(f,fun)
d = function(x) rbind(a, b[[x]])
d = lapply(f,d)
library(scales) 
fun <- function (x) rescale(d[[x]]$value, to = c(0,2*pi))
d$value <- lapply(f,fun)

# Now you can create the rescaled a and b vectors.
A <- function(x) d[[x]][d[[x]]$Source == "a", 1]
A <-lapply(f,A)
B <- function(x) d[[x]][d[[x]]$Source == "b", 1]
B <-lapply(f,B)

# You can then calculate the area of overlap as you did previously.
lower <- function (x) min(d[[x]]$value)-1 
lower <- lapply(f,lower)
upper <- function (x) max(d[[x]]$value)+1
upper <- lapply(f,upper)
# generate kernel densities
da <- function(x) density(A[[x]], from=lower[[x]], to=upper[[x]], adjust = 1)
da <- lapply(f,da)
db <- function (x) density(B[[x]], from=lower[[x]], to=upper[[x]],adjust = 1)
db <- lapply(f,db)
# Compute overlap coefficient
fun <- function(x) overlapTrue (da[[x]][[2]],db[[x]][[2]])
overlap <-lapply(f,fun)
```

Therefore what would be if my objective is to find out which of the overlap distributions (where you get the fit) or lack of fit is due to being within the distribution benchmark.

Comment: Please simplify your example.  Boil it down to a small sample set and try to omit extraneous code not pertinent to your example.

Comment: I have to generate a few distributions within another distribution, if I would use a random generation I will have to generate many as well, however I have reduced the number of variables. the second part is taken from a solution here